# Swagger Gen throws a null reference error in security scheme

Tags: rest, .net-core, oauth-2.0, swagger, .net-6.0

I recently updated my project from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 6.
I'm now getting an error in Swagger Oauth2 setup:

> System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
> at ProjectName.Startup.<>c.b__4_2(SwaggerGenOptions c)
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ConfigureSchemaGeneratorOptions.ConfigureSchemaGeneratorOptions(System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenOptions> swaggerGenOptionsAccessor) in :0

Code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    //.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Jwt_Authority"),
            ValidateLifetime = true
        };

        o.Authority = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Jwt_Authority");
        o.Audience = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Jwt_Audience");
        o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
        {
        };
    });

    services.AddControllers();
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;

    // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
        var tokenUrl = new Uri(new System.Uri(
                        new Uri("https://project:8443/auth/realms/master/"),
                        "protocol/openid-connect/token").AbsoluteUri);
        c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement() {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "oauth2"
                },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "oauth2",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            },
            new List <string> ()
            }
        });
        var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows =
            {
                Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    TokenUrl = tokenUrl,
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://project:8443/auth/realms/master/")
                }
            },
            Name = "oauth2",
            Scheme = "oauth2",
            
            //Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
            //{
            //    { "user_impersonation", "Access Bruce-WebAPI-NetCore" }
            //}
        };
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", securityScheme);
        
        //c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
       });
    }
}
```

These are the Swagger nuget versions used:

```
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.0.0" />
```